# How do i clear statusbar text wxwidgets c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
 void TestFrame::UpdateStatusBar(wxString color, wxString message)
{
  wxStatusBar* bar = wxFrame::GetStatusBar();
  bar->SetStatusText("", 0);
  wxStaticText* txt = new wxStaticText(bar, wxID_ANY, wxT(""), wxPoint(10, 5), wxDefaultSize, 0);
 bar->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(color));
 txt = new wxStaticText(bar, wxID_ANY, message, wxPoint(10, 5), wxDefaultSize, 0);
  txt->Show(true);
}
```

**Expected behavior**

Clear previous status bar text.
Add new text to statusbar

**Actual behavior**

The text is not cleared, new text is added on top and previous text overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you create a new wxStaticText with your wxStatusBar as the parent, rather than modifying any of the existing text fields you are creating an additional text object and setting the status bar as its parent. These will then persist until they are deleted.

You should be using bar->SetStatusText or bar->PushStatusText when you want to change the text of a particular existing field in the status bar.

Comment: how do i stop it from disappearing?

Comment: Status bar is not meant for the display of persistent messages. Use a separate control or `wxInfoBar` for this.

Answer (score -1):

This shoukd be enough:

```
void TestFrame::UpdateStatusBar(wxString color, wxString message)
{
    wxStatusBar* bar = GetStatusBar();
    bar->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(color));
    bar->SetStatusText(message, 0); //text in field 0
}
```

Notice that I deleted `wxFrame::` from GetStatusBar() because your `TestFrame` derives from `wxFrame`.

You can add a `wxStaticText` )or other controls) to the status bar. But this requires to handle size-event for the status bar on your own and position the added control-

Comment: how do i stop it from disappearing?

Comment: @StephenMooney, stop what from disappearing?

Comment: The statusbar text disappears after a second

Comment: If it disappears then you have another problem. Post more code, if possible a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)